# How to get to save games for continued play?

Tags: bejeweled-3

Like most folks, I want to see my score build in various games in Bejeweled 3. I even leave it open in my browser and don't use QUIT off the Bejeweled Menu and still when I go back to individual games, it does not see me as the same user and continue my cumulative scores. So ? - is the ONLY way to be the top scorer in all the games and thus win that badge is to play until you are dead in one long sitting for hours on end? Right now the scores include my 'remembered' player name 4 times in some of the score rankings I see on my game. I surely don't want to play against my own old scores! Others say QUEST Mode is won when all 5 artifacts are open and your score is >80%. I still cannot get mine to give me the Heros Welcome badge despite I am now at 94% with only 2 gems still needing fill in - 1 on chair and 1 on crown.

Answer (score 1):

If you're losing progress in a browser-based game, the most likely cause is cookies being deleted or not being saved at all. If the game is using Flash, you need to make sure your Flash plugin is set to allow cookies from the game's domain. See [this article](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-manage-flash-cookies.htm) or google "flash cookie management" to figure out how to do so. If the game is not flash-based, you will need to enable cookie saving for that domain in your browser, google "*name of browser* cookie management" for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

this does seem to be a glitch in your product, as mine always saves my game automatically and asks when I return if I want to play the same game or a new one. You should contact the manufacturer - is it EA?
you can google around and find them. Good luck!!!